# Reading multidimentional array in Controller passed from javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multidimensional-array

I am trying to send a multidimensional array to controller method by using following code.
I need help to read the json multi-dimentional array in controller.Can some one guide me how I can read the json.

```
 var arguments = new Array();

                var orderList= $('.orderList');
                /*get productId,quantity*/
                for (var i = 0; i < orderList.length; i++) {
                    arguments.push({
                        productId: orderList[i].id, 
                        quantity: orderList.children(".quantity")[i].value 
                        });

                }
                 $.ajax({
                    url: $(current).data().url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    traditional: true, 
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { "arguments": JSON.stringify(arguments), "userId": $('#UserId').val()},
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                                          }
                            } 
                      });
```

/* Controller Code */

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveExecutionOrder(List<string> arguments, int pageRegistryItemId)
    {
     /*The arguments are in Json, how should I read those ?
The arguments Array coming like this [{"productId":"2","quantity":"1"},{"productId":"1","quantity":"2"},{"productId":"4","quantity":"3"},{"productId":"3","quantity":"0"},{"productId":"6","quantity":"0"},{"productId":"5","quantity":"0"},{"productId":"23","quantity":"0"}]*/
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think receiving as a viewModel would be the easiest option. Create a viewModel according to your required data structure and receive that viewModel as parameter in your controller action.

```
public class OrderList
{
    public List<Order> OrderedItems { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherParameters { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveExecutionOrder(OrderList data)
    {
        //do some stuff
    }

Hope this helps